# Basic Azure Storage getting started. Create Scheduled File back up

Tags: azure, backup, azure-storage

This is probably a basic question but all I am looking for in Azure is the ability to back up files on my Windows Server at a scheduled time. MS SQL, MySQL and Web Site Files.

I have created a Trial account and a Storage plan but need a pointer to which section of the Dashboard I should be visiting - it isn't immediately apparent!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you are asking about backing up your Windows server running as a VM instance on Azure.

Below is the latest Azure VM backup guide from Microsoft.

Hope it helps!

[Azure virtual machine back up](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/backup-azure-vms/#initial-backup)